# Mongo ShardTag Range with Regex

Tags: mongodb

I am running Shard with 3 Replica, each Replica has 3 servers.

shard-1
shard-2
shard-3

I need some help regarding ShardTags, My Shard key is domain

now I want add TagRange something like this.

domains names start (^a to ^f) should go on shard-1 and domain start from (^f to ^m) should go to shard-2 and domain name start (^n to ^z) go to shard-3.

Is this possible?

Br.

Umar

Comment: yes, it's possible, you use the sh.addTagRange() command.  It's documented: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.addTagRange/

Comment: I know about this, My Question is about Regex Type TagRange, on docs.mongodb.org there is simple example.

Comment: you don't specify a regex, you specify the lowest value that should be in range and the lowest that shouldn't be.  So range 'a' to 'b' will be all strings that start with 'a'.

Comment: sh.addTagRange("dname.domains", {domain : 'a'}, { domain : 'g'}, "aDomains");

what is the mean of above range?